# Azure DevOps problem with Docker Images and builds tagging

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am moving our Ops part of the repository to a separate one. After that, I have a problem with tagging our builds and images.

[Example of wrong tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GseQ0.png)
[Example of correct tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSBSd.png)

This is my pipeline and templates:
Pipeline:

```
name: $(Date:yyyy.MM)$(Rev:.r)$(buildName)
pool: Azure Pipelines

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: X # In a different organization
    type: git
    name: X 
    ref: develop

parameters:
- name: refBranch
  displayName: Default ref branch (don't touch)
  type: string
  default: $[ resources.repositories['X'].ref ]

variables:
  - template: ../templates/build-variables.yaml

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build spark backend
    jobs:
    - job: BaseSteps
      displayName: Base steps
      steps:
      - template: ../templates/spark-base-steps.yaml
```

Variables:

```
variables:
- group: vargroup-build
- name: containerRegistry
  value: 'X'
- name: buildName
  ${{ if startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/develop') }}:
    value: -beta
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/feature/') }}:
    value: -alpha
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/hotfix/') }}:
    value: -hotfix
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/bugfix/') }}:
    value: -bugfix
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/release/') }}:
    value: -rc
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/master') }}:
    value: ''
  ${{ else }}:
    value: '-wrong-name-of-branch'

- name: buildTag
  ${{ if eq(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/develop') }}:
    value: beta
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/feature/') }}:
    value: alpha
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/hotfix/') }}:
    value: hotfix
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/bugfix/') }}:
    value: bugfix
  ${{ elseif startsWith(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/release/') }}:
    value: RC
  ${{ elseif eq(parameters.refBranch, 'refs/heads/master') }}:
    value: prod
  ${{ else }}:
    value: 'wrong-name-of-branch'
```

And base steps template:

```
steps:
  - checkout: Spark
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Add build Tag
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(buildTag)"

  - task: DockerInstaller@0
    inputs:
      dockerVersion: '24.0.6'
```

I tried to use $[ resources.repositories['X'].ref ] as a variable or even inside the variables template. The result is always "wrong-name-of-branch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test with the same YAML sample and I can reproduce the same situation.

It contains the following two limitations that make it unable to meet your needs.

1.When you define the parameter default value with the Variable, it will be treated as a string without expansion, so the correct value cannot be obtained.

2.The variable:**$[ resources.repositories['X'].ref ]** is a runtime variable. It will expand at runtime. But the If expression will expand at compile time. In this case, it will not get correct value and keep setting value: wrong name of branch.

For a workaround, you need to use the Bash script to check the value of the variable:**$[ resources.repositories['X'].ref ]** and use logging command to set the pipeline variable based on the ref info.

Here is an example:

```
variables:
- name: ref
  value: $[ resources.repositories['X'].ref ]
- name: containerRegistry
  value: 'X'



stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build spark backend
    jobs:
    - job: BaseSteps
      displayName: Base steps
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            if [ $(ref)  ==  "refs/heads/master" ]
            then
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildTag;]foo"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildname;]foo"
            else
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildTag;]wrong-name-of-branch"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildname;]wrong-name-of-branch"
            fi

      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: Add build Tag
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo $(tools.ref)
            echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(buildTag)"
            echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(buildname)"
```